# Problema en mi consulta Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Tengo una base de datos en donde controlo entras y salidas de trailers, más sin embargo cuando quiero hacer una consulta sobre que tractores que entraron y tambien salieron, se me repiten los registros, como se muestra a continuación, como que cruza los registros sobre las coincidencias, les pido mucho su apoyo:

consulta

```
SELECT entradas.idcom_tractores, entradas.tractor, entradas.fecha as fechaentrada, entradas.hora as entrada, salidas.fecha as fechasalida, salidas.hora as salidas 
FROM ala_planificador.entradas 
    inner join ala_planificador.salidas on ( entradas.tractor=salidas.tractor )  
where entradas.tractor=salidas.tractor;
```

resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tabla entrada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tabla salidas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a continuacion marco los registros duplicados, ya que solo entraron y salieron 2 veces y mi consulta me muestra 4 registros con las fechas y horas combinadas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! yo no veo ningun registro repetido.. segun vos, que registros se repiten? de paso, el where no tiene sentido es igual a la clausula inner join...

Comment: el registro 49 de la columna tractor, solo tiene 2 entradas y dos salidas, al igual que el gestro 90876, tiene dos entradas y dos salidas, por lo cual repiten 2 veces más los registros y se mezclan las fechas y horas

Comment: Y esta perfecto.. vos le estas diciendo que por cada entrada, para el codigo de tractor, las una con las salidas para el mismo codigo de tractor.. si hay 2 entradas, y dos salidas.. son 4 registros.. a vos, que te gustaria mostrar??? no hay magia aca ;)

Comment: es que justamente lo que necesito es alguna consulta que me pueda sar solo el 1 dato de entrada y de salida

Comment: eso, es otra cosa.. ahora defini, cual es el primer dato de entrada y cual de salida.. y aprende sobre group by, min y max....

Comment: el primer dato pertenecen a la tabla entradas (fecha, hora, idcom_tractores, tractor) y de la tabla salidas (fecha, hora, idcom_tractores, tractor). he estado investigando al respecto, aún estoy en ello

Comment: Mostra un ejemplo claro de lo que queres como salida... en una tabla no hay concepto de primero o ultimo, a menos que ordenes y definas vos que es primero o ultimo...

Comment: identradas idsalidas fechaentrada horaentrada idcom_remolques remolque fechasalida horasalida
2 2 13/12/2022 09:27:01 AKO 51 13/12/2022 11:20:27
3 3 13/12/2022 09:28:57 AKO 2846 13/12/2022 11:22:38

Que en este ultimo si agregara algun registro en la tabla entrada con un numero de tractor igual a los ya mostrados que no lo tome en cuenta ya que este ultimo no tiene una salida

Answer (score -1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que en este ultimo si agregara algun registro en la tabla entrada con un numero de tractor igual a los ya mostrados que no lo tome en cuenta ya que este ultimo no tiene una salida

algo asi @gbianchi

pero en mi alctual consulta si agrego una entrada de un tractor que ya tuvo una salda previa esta se muesta como a continuacion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este espacio es solo para respuestas a la pregunta, si necesitas agregar detalles a tu pregunta recuerda que puedes editarla.

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agrega la info en la pregunta.. igual no queda claro cual es la salida que queres.. lo que mostrar no tiene sentido...